# Is you or she followed by is or are in a sentence?

Tags: grammar

> I do not know whether you or Arpitha is on duty tomorrow.

Is it "is" or "are" after Arpitha? ( Context. There are two technicians- Annie and Arpitha. I am asking Annie. Only one person can be on duty at a time.)
Shouldn't it be- I do not know whether you or Arpitha are/is on duty tomorrow?

Comment: If that's a quote, please quote it (with a '> ' at the start of the line); and please could you provide a little more context? A correct answer *might* depend on the options available.

Answer (score 2):

It's **is** in this case. Subject is singular because it's either **you** or **Arpitha**, not both of you working at the same one.

Comment: What if both are, though? This is why I asked OP for more context.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is **is**.

Explanation:

The conjugation of "to be" in English is as follows:

- Infinitive: "To Be"
- 1st Person Singular: "I"
- 2nd Person Singular: "Are"
- 3rd Person Singular: "Is"
- 1st Person Plural: "Are"
- 2nd Person Plural: "Are"
- 3rd Person Plural: "Are"

In your sentence *"I do not know whether you or Arpitha [to be] on duty tomorrow"*, it can be tempting to think that "you or Arpitha" is plural, because it contains two people (Arpitha and You). But in reality it's singular, because only one of you is on duty, not both. Therefore, [to be] gets conjugated as 3rd personal singular, which is **"is"**.

Comment: What if both are, though? This is why I asked OP for more context.

Comment: "Or" implies that only one of them are on duty. "And" would imply both. Therefore, the assumption here is that both of them are not on duty. Thus, 3rd person singular is the correct form here.

Comment: Sorry, *when I first asked* they had not specified that only one could be on duty. Without that, one could not be so sure. In particular, *what if, when first asking / describing the situation, one didn't know whether it would be none, one or both?* Answering the question without knowing that ... I'd have gone with "is / are" in writing, probably "are" in speech.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you or Arithra is/are comming.

the correct helping verb is "is".

When all the elements in a series connected by or are singular, the verb they govern is singular. When all the elements are plural, the verb is plural. Example: Tom or Jack is coming (The Free Dictionary).